# how to enable file logging in spring boot jar

Tags: java, logging

I'm creating a spring boot jar for logging. And i have added this dependency in my main spring boot project. I can able to get the logs in console in my main project. But there are not logged into the file.

I have added the following in application.yml file

```
logging.file: MyApp.log
```

Can anyone please help me with this. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: what library are you using for logging `Logback`, `Log4j` ? Do you have a config file like `logback.xml` in your project ?

Comment: @OlivierBoissé: I am using Logback. I want to configure the logging in application.properties file.

Answer (score 1):

Some example in `.properties`

```
# Enable log in specific package
logging.level.br.com.package-project=DEBUG

# Define pattern in logs
logging.pattern.console=%d{HH:mm:ss.sss} %5p %40logger{36} : %msg%n


# name log file for springboot 2.2+
logging.file.name=log-file.log 

# name log file  for springboot 2.2-
# logging.file=log-file.log

# other properties for log file
# logging.file.max-size=900KB
# logging.file.total-size-cap=900KB

## Define log pattern for log file
logging.pattern.file=%d{HH:mm:ss.sss} %5p ${spring.application.name}:${server.port}/%logger{0} : %msg%n
```